# Pound sign shows as A£ when entering it into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that saves the price into the database but whn a user enters a £ sign it shows as A£ with a reflex accent over the A (dont know how to write one of those). It does not do this when i enter it in manually in phpmyadmin. The coalition of the price field is latin1 and it is a varchar so I don't see any problems with this. In the mysql query in the php the price has htmlspecialchars and mysql_real_escape_string on but I have taken thes off and the problem still persists.

Last of all it is not just displaying The £ sign differently, it is actually saving it into the database differently. How can I fix this?

Comment: what is the meta tag charset on your page set as?

Comment: possible help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703636/how-to-store-euro-symbol-in-mysql-database

Comment: can you show us what code you are using....are you using "&#163;" for pound sign..check space if its the somewhre before pound sign ..if yes trim..check meta tags it if it solves your problem let me know then

Comment: "dont know how to write one of those" With copy & paste?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888981/cannot-get-record-to-insert-into-mysql-data-using-php/11891450#11891450

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably save yourself a lot of grief in the long run if change the design of your application to store the values and currency in separate columns.

```
value | currency
----------------
10    | GBP
16.42 | USD
```

You can then parse your user input before adding to the database, whether it be `£10`, `10GBP`, or `Ten Pounds Sterling`, and format it appropriately when retrieving it from the database.

This will definitely make your life easier when it comes to supporting odder currencies, reacting to the change of a currency symbol (yes, [that happens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hryvnia_sign)), dealing with exchange rates over time, and outputting data to places other than a website.

Comment: This is definitely the appropriate solution if you are doing anything other than simple data display.  Never store currency information as anything other than a number and currency indicator tuple!  That is the road to madness.

Comment: I think this is the option I will take. Lack of caffiene has stopped me from thinking straight

Answer (score 6):

This is usually caused by the character set of the connection and the user of the string disagreeing.  For example, the connection character set could be returning UTF-8 and the PHP script might treat the string as iso-latin-1 which would cause exactly this.  I'm not sure how these properties are set in PHP.

In the `mysql` CLI you can see the various properties using `SHOW VARIABLES`:

```
mysql> show variables like '%char%';
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                                   |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                                                  |
| character_set_connection | latin1                                                  |
| character_set_database   | latin1                                                  |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                                  |
| character_set_results    | latin1                                                  |
| character_set_server     | latin1                                                  |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                                    |
| character_sets_dir       | C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\share\charsets\ |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

I would start looking in that direction.  The indication here is that you are seeing multiple characters when you are expecting a single character.  Anything outside of the 7-bit range will be encoded into multiple UTF-8 octets.

**UTF-8 Details**

- "£" is the iso-latin-1 codepoint `0xA3`
- `0xA3` encoding using UTF-8 results in the bytes `0xC2`, `0xA3`
- `0xC2` and `0xA3` are represented by the iso-latin-1 glyphs "Â£"