# Cannot get record to insert into mysql data using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP to populate a database of company records.  I have a field for company name and the currency type that they use.
But when I use PHP the record never gets inserted if the currency is an Enlglish pound sign (£).  A dollar sign ($) or any other normal character is no problem.  The record with a pound sign inserts just fine when I run the sql statement and enter it directly into MySQL Query Browser.  But it just doesn't work when I run the exact same INSERT statement in PHP.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO company_test (name, currency) VALUES ('ABC Widgets', '£')";   
$rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
//Does not insert a record

$sql = "INSERT INTO company_test (name, currency) VALUES ('ABC Widgets', '$')";   
$rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
//A record inserts just fine

//My MySQL version is 5.5.11.  PHP is version 5.3.6.  
//The MySQL table looks like this:
TABLE company_test
FIELD | id       | INTEGER(10) | not null | auto increment
FIELD | name     | VARCHAR(45) | not null
FIELD | currency | VARCHAR(3)
```

In MySQL Query Browser the "Table Options" tab shows that for this company_test table my charset is utf8.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the charset of PHP script? ASCII or UTF8? Do you get any warnings from mysql? Did you tried calling mysql_error()?

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons).

Comment: Is it worth maybe increasing the size of the `currency` field? I've no idea if a pound sign would be stored as one character or as something like `&pound;`, which wouldn't fit....

Comment: Keep in mind that `£` is not an ASCII character. Inserting the record correctly will require matching your character sets in PHP, the database connection, and the database itself.

Comment: Also check the character set that the MySQL database is using.  The £ character may not be allowed.  Take PHP out of the mix and try to do the same query inside MySQL.

Comment: Currency should be specified using the correct [ISO code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) with a look-up table that converts from codes to formatted currency values. Inserting currency symbols is useless since Mexico, Costa Rica and the United States all use '$' to mean completely different things.

Comment: pass value from javascript                                                                                like this-> var x=escape($('#xyz'.val()));                                                                       AND Receive value in PHP                                                                             like this ->$x=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['xyz']);      Then pass $x into sql query....                                                                             $sql = "INSERT INTO company_test (name, currency) VALUES ('ABC Widgets', '$x')";        Its worked for me ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for errors:

```
$rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Never assume a query succeeds. Even if your sql syntax is perfect, there's far too many other reasons for failure to NOT check.

Answer (score 1):

After some Googling I finally found something that worked.  Somebody with a similar probably created a PHP function that converts the character set of the sql statement.
Now my query looks like this before being inserted:
INSERT INTO company_test (name, currency) VALUES ('ABC Widgets', 'Â£')
Notice the funny little character before the pound sign.

Anyways here is the function:

```
function TtoUtf8( &$string, $encType = 'ISO-8859-1' ) 
{ 
    $enc    = mb_detect_encoding( $string ); 
    $enc ? 
        $enc = $enc : 
        $enc = $encType; 
    if ( $enc == 'UTF-8' ) 
    { 
        return $string; 

        // end if $enc == UTF-8 
    } else 
    { 
        $conv = iconv( $enc, 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $string ); 
        $conv ? 
            $ret = &$conv : 
            $ret = &$string; 
        return $ret; 
    }
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you convert it first to htmlentities or htmlspecialchar:

```
$currency = htmlspecialchars('£');
$sql = "INSERT INTO company_test (name, currency) VALUES ('ABC Widgets', '{$currency}')";
```

Also, what type of datatype is your currency field?

Comment: I increased the varchar size of the curreny field to 10.  That didn't work.  The currency field is datatype utf8.  I just output the value of the mysql_error and get this -> 1366: Incorrect string value: '\xA3' for column 'currency' at row 1

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is **nowhere** close to escaping this for SQL. Please use the proper methods.

Comment: Yea, I tried raygo's htmlspaecialchars function and received the same error.

Comment: Try to put SET NAMES latin1; in before the INSERT $sql = "SET NAMES latin1; INSERT INTO ..."