# Currency Symbols are Not Getting Stored in mySql db using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am reading an array into my database but the currencySymbol always gets stored as a 0 instead of the actual symbol.  All other data is stored as expected.  I cannot even begin to think how to solve.  Any help appreciated.

Here is a short sample of my array with currencySymbol.  The actual list is much longer.

```
      [AF] => Array
            (
                [alpha3] => AFG
                [currencyId] => AFN
                [currencyName] => Afghan afghani
                [currencySymbol] => ؋
                [id] => AF
                [name] => Afghanistan
            )

        [AI] => Array
            (
                [alpha3] => AIA
                [currencyId] => XCD
                [currencyName] => East Caribbean dollar
                [currencySymbol] => $
                [id] => AI
                [name] => Anguilla
            )
```

Update:  I don't know why but the field type was set to int.  I changed it to varchar and changed the collation to utf16_unicode_ci and it worked.

[image]

Comment: How does your schema look like?

Comment: Where is the code, which stores the data?

Comment: look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703636/how-to-store-euro-symbol-in-mysql-database)

Comment: probably you have specified a default value for the column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating database table use utf8_unicode_ci in options column which you want to save currencySymbol.